# switching css class on multiple divs

Tags: jquery, css

```
<div class='checked' id='rb01'></div>
<div class='rb' id='rb02'></div>
<div class='rb' id='rb03'></div>
```

these are buttons. clicking I need to switch css class.

```
$(".rb").click(function() {
    $('.checked').addClass('rb');  // doesn't work
    $(this).addClass('checked');  // works
});
$("#rb01").click(function() {  // all works
    $('#player').attr('src', '//www.youtube.com/embed/x13hzEsEPe0?rel=0');
});
$("#rb02").click(function() {
    $('#player').attr('src', '//www.youtube.com/embed//pKfRAq4PPIQ?rel=0');
});
$("#rb03").click(function() {
    $('#player').attr('src', '//www.youtube.com/embed/hiZIEB1776g?rel=0');
});
```

Comment: the addClass is working http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/emQ7s/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny, i checked your fiddle, it doeesn't work for me. firefox 24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try;

```
$('.checked').removeClass().addClass('rb');
```

Comment: btw why i can't type here `@` and get a suggestion name. It works only on the section just bellow the question, but not on the answers section ?

Comment: your'e welcome @SunSky. Don't forget to mark this answer as accepted by clicking check mark..

Comment: may be because u have a less reputation (612)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(".rb").on("click",function(){
    $('#player').attr('src', '//www.youtube.com/embed//pKfRAq4PPIQ?rel=0');
});
```

Comment: Hiral, I think you didn't understand the question. Please focus on `doesn't work` line.

Comment: @SunSky You haven't asked any question!